# Can we send data from different url's into different index in elastic search using one single logstash config file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Using http poller as input plugin and elastic search as output plugin can we send data from different urls into different indicies in elasticsearch using one single logstash config file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using [`if` conditions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) in the output section:

```
input {
    http_poller {
        ...
        add_tag => "source1"
    }
    http_poller {
        ...
        add_tag => "source2"
    }
}
filter {
    ...
}
output {
    if "source1" in [tags] {
         elasticsearch {
             ...
             index => "index1"
         }
    }
    else if "source2" in [tags] {
         elasticsearch {
             ...
             index => "index2"
         }
    }
}
```